# The implications of using MCMC normalization algorithm output as input in a separate normal linear model (and similar combined approaches in general)

Tags: regression, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, biostatistics, algorithms

**Background**

I am a statistics intern (not assigned a supervisor yet) in a medical research institute. I’m exploring methods for network analysis in the context of multi-omics data, focused on microbial abundances and metabolite data. Currently, I am experimenting with Gaussian Graphical Model-based methods that would account for characteristics of microbiome abundance data (compositional, zero-inflated, overdispersed) and confounder variables gathered from the environment (different medical statuses and measurements, e.g. disease status, some blood measurement, BMI). My ultimate goal with these methods is to explore associations and structures within given data and suggest hypotheses about taxa-taxa relations for further analysis.

**Initial Model**

I am currently investigating a method described in the article “HARMONIES: A Hybrid Approach for Microbiome Networks Inference via Exploiting Sparsity” by S. Jiang et al which can be found here: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fgene.2020.00445/full

Specifically, I am interested in using the Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial (ZINB) model-based normalization technique they described, then using the normalized abundance counts with Gaussian Graphical Model (GGM) methods. It is based on a following ZINB model for the taxonomic count matrix and indicator function $\mbox{I}$:

$y_{ij} \sim \pi_i \mbox{I}(y_{ij}=0) + (1-\pi_i)\mbox{NB}(\lambda_{ij}, \phi_j), \ \ for \ y_{ij},\ i = 1, …, n, \ j = 1, …, p.$

Which can be described as a hierarchical Bayesian model:

$\begin{cases}
y_{ij} = 0, \ \ if \ \ \eta_{ij}=1,\\
y_{ij} \sim \mbox{NB}(s_i \alpha_{ij}, \phi_j), \ \ if \ \ \eta_{ij}=0,\\
\log \alpha_{ij} \sim \mbox{N}(\mu_j, \sigma_j^2)
\end{cases}$

Where $\eta_{ij} \sim \mbox{Bernoulli}(\pi_i)$, with prior $\pi_i \sim \mbox{Beta}(a_\pi, b_\pi)$, a $\mbox{Gamma}(a_\phi, b_\phi)$ prior for $\phi_j$, mean parameter $\lambda_{ij}=s_i \alpha_{ij}$, where $s_i$ is a sample-specific size factor factor and $\alpha_{ij}$ **is the "normalized abundance"**, with priors $\mu_j \sim \mbox{N}(0, h_0 \sigma_0^2)$ (suggested parameters so prior is flat for $\mu_0^2$)  and $\sigma_j^2 \sim \mbox{Inverse-Gamma}(a_0, b_0)$.

The authors of the paper implemented a MCMC algorithm that estimates parameters of the above model, including the "normalized abundance" $\alpha_{ij}$, which they then pass onto Graphical LASSO.

**My Suggestion: Bayesian Linear Model**

Assume there is a set of confounding environmental covariates that have a linear relationship with abundance. I am still interested in the ZINB Bayesian normalization technique, but I also want to account for this additional linear dependence. With this in mind, the simplest approach I could think of is Bayesian linear model and modify my "normalized abundance" as following:

$\log \alpha_{ij}=z_{ij}+\mu_{0j}+x_i \beta_j^T$

Where we have Q-dimensional (for Q covariates) vectors $x_i$ and $\beta_j \sim \mbox{N}(0, \sigma_{\beta j}^2)$, error value $z_{ij} \sim \mbox{N}(0, \sigma_{\alpha j}^2)$ and baseline $\mu_{0j} \sim \mbox{N}(0, h_0 \sigma_{0j}^2)$, with weakly informative Inverse-Gamma priors for sigmas. With the goal of determining the covariance matrix for errors.

**My Questions**

There already exists an implemented MCMC algorithm for normalization of abundance data as described above. However, their implementation is non-trivial to quickly modify it to include the linear relationship I suggested. And even then, I am not sure if my own suggestion would be good compared to other approaches. Thus, I am looking for simpler ways to explore things, sacrificing rigour if need be, but I want to do it consciously and for it to make sense.

I have the following questions:

1. First of all, I am looking to confirm that my suggestion would work for getting a covariance matrix to then use for exploring associations between taxa (assumedly free of covariate confounding).
2. My current idea to do it in a "lazy" way: First, I normalize the abundance data with already implemented MCMC method and then use its output (being "normalized abundance counts") to further perform a regression or other separate downstream modeling or analysis (for example using my Bayesian suggestion in regression). Does this carry any practical sense, and what practical and theoretical implications would such an approach have for my problem? I’m struggling to wrap my head around any potential problems and their solutions.
3. In general, what practical and theoretical red flags arise from the creation of such downstream schemes, using outputs of one model as input in a different one or mixing Bayesian and Frequentist approaches to inference?

I couldn’t find a lot of information that would direct me with these issues, at least not in an elaborated way, either being opinions or experience that are not explained a lot or some papers and answers writing about adjacent issues which didn’t really provide me with enough clarity to be confident and move on. However, maybe, I just didn’t look good enough.

So, basically, it would be really convenient to generally use other methods for denoising or normalizing in sequence with other models or analytic methods, but I would like to know justifications/limitations of this. All in all, thank you very much for considering this question.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you heard of programs like JAGS or stan? These are great ways to prototype Bayesian models.

Comment: @JohnMadden Thank you for your comment. I know of these programs, but I have never worked with them before and learned of them very recently. My experience is entirely confined within R and Python as of now. 

However, I am going through some tutorials for JAGS right now and also familiar with brms package that extends from stan. My thought was to implement this simple linear model one way or the other and then use it on the results of the data normalization algorithm output from the article. At least for the time being.

Comment: Oh I kinda danced around your central question cause I don't know much epidemiology. But in my view it's a great idea to do the "simple" thing first, because it's usually harder than you think. And if you have time after, you can try the more sophisticated approach. Indeed, in order to show that your sophisticated approach is worth it, you would need to compare to something simpler. So in a sense, no work is wasted.

Comment: @JohnMadden Yeah, my idea with this "lazy" approach is essentially to sacrifice perfect rigour in favour of easy implementation to compare it with other approaches to constructing association networks and to make a decision whether a more rigorous/complex implementation would be worth the time.
However even with this easy approach, I still want to be conscious what it could entail. I am basically putting estimates for one model into a procedure for a separate one. I tried to look what kind of practical and theoretical issues this could create, but couldn't find anything elaborate.

Comment: people do this kinda stuff all the time; I think "ML pipelines" or something like that is the right phrase to Google. Since your first method is Bayesian, you can be extra careful and generate several samples for your abundance scores, doing your downstream analysis separately on each and propagating some uncertainty.